# Excel XLL function linkage / race condition causing #NAME

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna, xll

I have a `C# ExcelDna XLL` function library that I register during startup from a VSTO add-in.

```
this.Application.RegisterXLL(xllPath);
```

When I shell execute an Excel file (`Process.Start` the `.xlsx` file) then most of the time everything works and the functions evaluate when the workbook opens.

When opening the workbook in this manner Excel reuses a currently running `EXCEL.EXE` process if one exists. Most of the time this is fine, but under certain conditions, for example if `Excel` was opened through `COM` and then closed, then when the Excel instance is closed, it doesn't really close, but instead shuts down all of its add-ins and unregisters all `XLLs` but remains alive. When process invoking into one of these zombie processes the functions, obviously, no longer evaluate.

To attempt to get around this I have tried to open Excel directly, using the `.xlsx` file as a command line parameter, but in this case there seems to be some kind of race condition and the workbook opens before the `XLL` has finished registering and the functions always evaluate as `#NAME`. If the cell is modified and reevaluated then the function correctly evaluates. Calling `Application.CalculateFull()` and all possible variations has no effect.

If I open a file via Explorer (i.e. double clicking on it) then strangely it now returns `#N\A` rather than `#NAME` but still it is the same problem.

I've even tried registering the `XLL` so it loads on start-up ([see here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/exceldna/d2ogsPkv6YM/NGnSrU9tmpMJ)) and it still doesn't work.

Has anyone else encountered this and found a reliable way to get `XLL` functions to evaluate when opening an Excel instance?

Comment: "when the Excel instance is closed, it doesn't really close" , I believe this is the only problem you need to focus on. Did you call,  `workbook.close()` and `excel.Quit()` when Excel is opened trough COM ? You shouldn't get a zombie Excel instance.

Comment: If it was me that was opening the COM instance, then it wouldn't be a problem. The problem is that anyone can leave a dangling COM instance hanging around.

Comment: ok, then maybe you can try to start Excel with the `/x` switch (to get a new instance). https://support.office.com/en-us/article/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#ID0EAABAAA=Excel

Comment: Tried that. "To attempt to ..."

Answer (score 0):

We've found that, if the Add-In isn't loaded properly and the functions don't calculate, performing a global search and replace (e.g. search for `=` replace with `=`) forces a recalc when the regular recalc doesn't work. You could potentially automate this with VBA `Application.OnTime`

Comment: I see, but I guess the problem is knowing when you are in that state. Also for us a macro is not going to be a viable solution as the workbook could be an xlsx, or macros could be disabled.

Comment: You are already distributing an XLL Add-In; so you could also distribute a .XLAM Add-In and require that both be installed.